# How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?

Tags: css

How does the [CSS Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) work?

CSS2.1 specifications says that in a block formatting context, boxes are laid out vertically, starting at the top. This happens even if there are floated elements in the way, except if the block box established a new block formatting context. As we know, when browsers render block boxes in a block formatting context, the floated element is omitted, why does establishing a new block formatting context work?

How are boxes (block boxes and inline boxes) laid out in the normal flow?

I read somewhere that block elements generate block boxes, but floating elements are ignored when a user agent draws box and take them into account when they fill out content. Whilst floating elements will overlap other elements's boundary of the boxes, the solution is establishing a new block formatting context for the overlapped elements using `overflow:hidden`.

"New block formatting context is still block formatting", so when drawing a box, it will also treat the floating element as if it doesn't exit. Is that right or have I misunderstood "new block formatting context?"

### Update:more questions

> By saying "It's this behaviour that's useful for columnar style layouts. The main use of it however is to stop floats, say in a "main content" div, actually clearing floated side columns, i.e. floats that appear earlier in the source code."

I don't understand the meaning, I will provide an example, maybe you will understand me.

```css
.content {
  background: #eee;
  color #000;
  border: 3px solid #444;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
.float {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}
p {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h3>This is a content box</h3>
  <p>It contains a left floated box, you can see the actual content div does go under the float, but that it is the &lt;h3&gt; and &lt;p&gt; <b>line boxes</b> that are shortened to make room for the float. This is normal behaviour.</p>
  <div class="float">floated box</div>
</div>
```

I thought the floating box should float to the top of the containg block-the div with class `content`. Besides, if the floating box appears earlier in the markup, then it will display what I think it should be.

```css
.content {
  background: #eee;
  color #000;
  border: 3px solid #444;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
.float {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}
p {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="float">floated box</div>
  <h3>This is a content box</h3>
  <p>it contains a left floated box, you can see the actual content div does go under the float, but that it is the &lt;h3&gt; and &lt;p&gt; <b>line boxes</b> that are shortened to make room for the float, this is normal behaviour</p>
</div>
```

How can we explain this? Can we use "block formatting context and inline formatting context" to explain it?

Comment: Could you add an image to document what you don't understand?

Comment: I know that you don't explicitly asked about floats, but I think [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) is really good in explaining how the flow of a web page works, and it may help you in understanding this.

Comment: An example and some explanation here: https://gist.github.com/aderchox/e3026ad0e28896794c481f30ee79279d

Answer (score 131, accepted):

**[Block Formatting Contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)**

> Floats, absolutely positioned
> elements, block containers (such as
> inline-blocks, table-cells, and
> table-captions) that are not block
> boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow'
> other than 'visible' (except when that
> value has been propagated to the
> viewport) **establish new block formatting contexts** for their contents.

With my bold, it's the **establish** bit that is important

What this means is that the element you use `overflow` (anything other than visible) or `float` or `inline-block`..etc on becomes responsible for the layout of its child elements. It's the child elements which are then "contained", whether that's floats or collapsing margins they should be wholly contained by their bounding  parent.

> In a block formatting context, each
> box's left outer edge touches the left
> edge of the containing block (for
> right-to-left formatting, right edges
> touch)

**What the above line means:**

Because a box can only be rectangular and not irregular shaped this means a new block formatting context between two floats (or even beside one) will not wrap around neighbouring side floats. The inner, child boxes can only extend as far as to touch their parents left (or right in RTL) edge. It's this behaviour that's useful for columnar style layouts. The main use of it however is to stop floats, say in a "main content" div, actually clearing floated side columns, i.e. floats that appear earlier in the source code.

---

**[Float Clearance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control)**

In normal circumstances floats are supposed to clear all previous floated elements, that's previously floated in the whole source code, not just your displayed "column"
The telling quote from the "float clearance specs" is:

> This property indicates which sides of
> an element's box(es) may not be
> adjacent to an earlier floating box.
> The 'clear' property does not consider
> floats inside the element itself or **in other block formatting contexts**

So say you have a three column layout where the left and right columns are floated left and right respectively, the side columns are now in new Block Formatting Contexts, because they are floated (remember float is also one of the properties that establish a new BFC), so you can happily float list elements inside them and they only clear floats which are already inside the side columns they no longer care about floats previously in the source code

---

##To make the main content a new Block Formatting Context or not?

Now that middle column, you can simply margin it from both sides so that it appears to sit neatly between the two side floated columns and take the remaining width, a common way to get desired width if the centre column is "fluid" - which will be fine until you need to use floats/clearance inside your content div (a common occurrence for those using "clearfix" hacks or templates including them)

Take this very simple code:

```css
#left-col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
}
#right-col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 180px;
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
}
#content {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 200px;
}
.floated {
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #dad;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-col">left column</div>
<div id="right-col">right column</div>

<div id="content">
  <h3>Main Content</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum etc..</p>
  <div class="floated">this a floated box</div>
  <div class="floated">this a floated box</div>
</div>
```

It produces the following:

[image]

In general this is fine, especially if you have no background colours or internal (in the main content) floats -  notice the floats are fine (not cleared yet) they're doing probably what you except them to **but** they, the `H3`'s top margin and the `p`'s bottom margin are not actually really contained by the content div (lightgrey background).

So to the same simple margined scenario of above code add:

```css
.clear-r {clear: right;}
```

to the CSS, and change the second HTML floated box to:

```
<div class="floated clear-r"> this a floated cleared box</div>
```

```css
#left-col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
}
#right-col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 180px;
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
}
#content {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 200px;
}
.floated {
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #dad;
}
.clear-r {
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-col">left column</div>
<div id="right-col">right column</div>

<div id="content">
  <h3>Main Content</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum etc..</p>
  <div class="floated">this a floated box</div>
  <div class="floated clear-r">this a floated cleared box</div>
</div>
```

This time you get this:

[image]

The second float is clearing the right side but it's clearing the whole height of the right column. The right column is floated earlier in the source code so it's clearing it as told! Probably not the desired effect though, also note the `h3` and `p` margins are still collapsed (not contained).

---

###Make it establish a Block Formatting Context, for the sake of the children!

and finally make the main content column take responsibility - **become a Block Formatting Context** - for its contents : remove `margin: 0 200px;` from the main content CSS and **ADD** `overflow: hidden;` and you get this:

```css
#left-col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
}
#right-col {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 180px;
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
}
#content {
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.floated {
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #dad;
}
.clear-r {
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-col">left column</div>
<div id="right-col">right column</div>

<div id="content">
  <h3>Main Content</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum etc..</p>
  <div class="floated">this a floated box</div>
  <div class="floated clear-r">this a floated cleared box</div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is probably much more like what you would expect to happen, note now the floats are contained, they clear properly ignoring the right side column, and also the `h3` and `p` margins are contained instead of collapsed.

With the extensive use of resets these days the margins are less noticeable (and IE still doesn't get them quite right) however what just happened to the centre "main content" is that it became a Block Formatting Context and is now responsible for its own child (descendant) elements. It's actually very similar to Microsoft's early days notion of hasLayout, it uses the same properties `display: inline-block`, `float`, and `overflow` anything other than visible, and of course table cells always have layout.. it is however without the bugs ;)

---

##Update: re more information in question:

When you say "but floating elements are ignored when user agent draws box and take them into account when they fill out content."

Yes floats normally overlay their container boxes, is that what you mean about parent boundaries? When a block element is drawn and it contains a float the block parent itself is drawn as a rectangle under the float and it is the "inline anonymous boxes" or simply "line boxes" of the other child elements that are shortened to make room for the float

Take this code:

```css
#content {
  background: #eee;
  color #000;
  border: 3px solid #444;
}
.float {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
p {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="float">floated box</div>
  <h3>This is a content box</h3>
  <p>it contains a left floated box, you can see the actual content div does go under the float, but that it is the &lt;h3&gt; and &lt;p&gt; <b>line boxes</b> that are shortened to make room for the float, this is normal behaviour</p>
</div>
```

Which produces this:

[image: how floats work]

You see that the parent element doesn't actually contain the float, as in it doesn't wrap it entirely.. the float is simply **floating** on top of the content - if you were to keep adding content to the div it would eventually wrap underneath the float because there would be no need for the (anonymous) "line boxes" of the `p` element to shorten themselves any more.

I've coloured the paragraph element so you can see that it too actually goes under the float, the darkgray background is where the paragraph starts, the white text is where the "anonymous line box" starts - it's only actually them that "make room" for the float, unless you tell it otherwise (i.e. you change the context)

Again referring to the above picture, if you were to margin the left side of the`p` element, yes it will stop the text wrapping under the bottom of the float because the "line boxes" (the white text) will only touch the left edge of their container, and you will bring the coloured background of the `p` to the right, clear of the float, but you won't have changed the behaviour of the `p`'s formatting context. Like the centre column in the first picture way above ;)

Comment: clairesuzy,thank you very much! It really helps me a lot.But i still have some questions.I have added it to the original questions.i hope you can help me.

Comment: @eileen there's two things going on - I think your extra question is explained by the first example.. the purple floated boxes appear after the content because that's where they are in the source, a float does not float to the top, go above previous content (as in it's top margin cannot be higher than where it should be) - the left and right columns are also floated boxes which are earlier in the source and without the middle column becoming a new BFC if you try and clear the purple floats they will also clear the earlier in source side floated columns.. does that help?

Comment: @eileen - if you do want the elements to appear "inline" as in side by side you would also float the content left, as well as floating your box right.. in which case the main container should again become a new Block formatting Context so that it actually contains the two lots of floats.

Comment: It absolutely helps me!I totally understand that.But, i still have questions about block formatting context. there is different between block formatting context and block formatting?Beacuse you said"have changed the behaviour of the p's formatting context."[example](http://www.mattryall.net/blog/2008/08/css-layout-fundamentals-block-and-inline-boxes) I really want to know how block elements and inline elements are rendering when having floating element in it.

Comment: @clairesuzy-The reason p's border is overlapped by floated box is because user agent doesn't take floated box into account when drawing p's border.That is block formatting.But why if it establishes a new block formatting context, it won't be overlapped by floated box.They are both a block formatting context, why is the behavior different?

Comment: @eileen that link is describing block level elements and inline  level element, just the basics not so much in a formatting context. block elements will always take 100% width and sit on top of each other (by default) - inline elements sit side by side, like links, spans etc.. the don't even take a width or height so they have no option. A floated element automatically becomes a block level element, so if you float an inline level `<span>` it becomes like a block level `<div>`.

Comment: cont.. The Block formatting Context is not the same thing .. this describes the context to which each element, or group of elements belongs, the responsible context is the one which takes responsibility for formatting/containing it's child elements and their float/clearance areas.

Comment: cont.. the reason the `p`'s background goes under the float is because floated elements are removed from the flow, as in the neighbouring elements really don't know they're there, and because they belong to the same formatting context the `p` looks to it's parent container for it's dimensions.. (that's why you can't put a 100% wide thing next to a float - because to it 100% is 100% of the container. Only the anonymous boxes finally figure out the float is there ;)

Comment: You are absolutely a legend!You understand css deeply!

Comment: @clairesuzy-if i set p element property overflow:hidden, then p establishes a new block formatting context for its child-anonymous boxes.Why p's box shrinks to adapt to the anonymous boxes?I kow what you mean by saying"context is the one whick takes responsibility for formatting/containing its child elements".But, i don't understand "...their float/clearance areas".

Comment: @eileen, Thank You! & yes, if you set overflow hidden on the `p` it establishes a new context for `p`'s descendants, in this case the `p` doesn't have any, I could've used a div in that example :) - That is exactly why the whole `p` (or any block level element) then shortens to not be under the side floats, if it did have descendants, they would now know exactly where their boundary edges are, for sizing and if any floats are descendants they would know to clear to only this new context edge rather than the old `#content` edge :)

Comment: @clairesuzy - The image you posted is out, could you please repost?

Comment: @clairesuzy - maybe use imageshack, which has more permanent images?

Comment: @huyz ta.. but I'm tying to use stack's own, if it doesn't work here where does it work.. why only one went I don't know, but I'll ask

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without making the overflowing content hidden?

Comment: Top link is outdated.