# Overriding overflow: hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a parent container with a lot of child elements. Due to animation reasons (child elements sliding in and out of the parent) I have set it's `overflow` property to `hidden`.

This works great but there are a couple of the children who I do want to be visible outside the parent's bounds.

How do I make it so that only certain children are visible outside the parent's bounds?

Comment: There is this wonderful thread on stackoverflow which you will love: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work

Comment: FYI, I added an example fiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer is: You can't. Either the parent has `overflow:hidden` then all child-elements will be clipped, or you have `overflow:(visible|auto|scroll|...)` then all children are treated according to that rule. There is no possibility you could mix states - all children are treated equally.

However, you could introduce additional container-elements inside the parent (which no longer has overflow:hidden) like in this pseudo-code:

```
<parent>    
   <container1 style="overflow:hidden">
      <!-- these will be clipped -->
      <element>
      <element>
   </container>

   <container2 style="overflow:visible">
      <!-- these will be shown -->
      <element>
      <element> 
   </container>
</parent>
```

edit: **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/esUD2/)**

Answer (score 1):

**In the light of more discussion with OP, this answer doesn't help. Instead see comments for clarification with OP.**

Firstly, it helps if you include some specific code.

Generically speaking, provide a `CSS` selector that is more specific to the child than the one that sets the `overflow: hidden;`

For instance,

**Style:**

```
.hide-children div {overflow: hidden;}
.hide-children div.show-me {overflow: none;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="hide-children">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child show-me"></div>
</div>
```

*But like I said, only after some sample code can a more meaningful answer be provided.*

Comment: That would set the child's overflow not change the parent's overflow in relation to it. Specific code would overcomplicate the matter I just need to know the theory.

Comment: wait, I did the edit before I saw you comment, so it might be irrelevant.

Comment: So, if I understamd you correctly, if there are 5 children in a parent that has it's overflow as hidden, then you want, say, 3 to be hidden when outside the bounds, but 2 to be visible?. If this is right, is there a possibility of adding scripts to handle this?

Comment: that is indeed what I would like, javascript / jQuery is fine also.

Comment: Right, as @christoph has said, it's not possible. But here's some food for thought: imagine your code has an outer `div` *u* that holds the parent-`div` *p* that contains the 5 children. Now, in *u*, have a copy of the 3 children that will escape the bounds of *p* positioned appropriately with their `visibility: hidden`. Now, detect when each of the 3 children go beyond the bounds of *p* and make their clone visible in  *u*.

Answer (score 1):

For me I got around it by making the parent with overflow:hidden bigger and then giving minus margins to surrounding elements.