# override parent overflow:hidden with child overflow:visible

Tags: html, css, overflow, parent-child

I have a header which is the parent of the nav and logo. I have set the parent to overflow:hidden so I was able to add margin-top to the nav to get it to sit at the bottom. However it clips the logo div as well. I was trying follow this question...[Overriding overflow: hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584020/overriding-overflow-hidden)

so tried to set the logo to overflow:visible but that hasn't worked either. I am not sure of any other solution other than the logo not being in the parent container.

Here is my code

CSS:

```
.container {
width: 960px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color: blue;
}

header {
height: 100px;
background-color: #001D5D;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

}

#logo {
height:100px;
width:100px;
z-index:10;
top:0px;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
}

nav {
    background-color:#1CCEAE;
    margin-top:63px; 
}

nav ul {
width:100%;
line-height: 37px;
    text-align:right;
    background-color:#1CCEAE; 

 }

ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
}

ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1em;
color:white;    
}
```

Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/XS3Zs/

Answer (score 1):

remove `width:100%` to `ul` or reset `padding` to `0` to `ul`.

`<ul>` doesn't really need `width:100%;` since it is a `block` element, it will use all `width` avalaible., width set to 100% may be too much. Borders, margin and padding will not be estimated.

Comment: Ok but how would I go about making the logo extend outside of the nav box? As there is overflow:hidden applied to parent header. It seems I need this property for the nav bar.

Comment: Then it should be nav in absolute position at bottom : 0; http://jsfiddle.net/XS3Zs/3/ so header grows with height of logo.

Comment: Ok I had it like that before but I was trying to find other alternatives to absolutely positioning, I guess that is the only solution I'll try that cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The UL element has by default `padding-left:40px;` so if you set that to 0 it will be fine.

I updated your [**[FIDDLE]**](http://jsfiddle.net/XS3Zs/2/)