# CSS float with border

Tags: css, css-float

I have a div that I would like to have a border and background-color, but the container has collapsed because everything is floated.

This can be see at http://jsfiddle.net/5DNFs/

How do I get the `<div class="due-total">` to have the border and background-color?

Comment: is it normal? I dont see the html and the css in ur fiddle?

Comment: Can't you just use a table? Seems like table data to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear your floats : [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v413hav/5DNFs/6/)

Note: Just changed border color so that you can see, you can change it to whatever you want

HTML

```
<div class="invoice-totals">   
    <div class="total">
        <div class="label">TOTAL</div>
        <div class="value">133.00</div>
    </div>

    <div class="paid-total">
        <div class="label">Payments</div>
        <div class="value">0.00</div>
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="due-total">
        <div class="label">AMOUNT DUE</div>
        <div class="value">133.00</div>
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is another way to clear without extra markup. http://jsfiddle.net/5DNFs/10/

Comment: @MaximeMorin did you read the issues using `overflow: hidden;` http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Most of these issues have been fixed.  No need of width to trigger hasLayout, zoom works.  Hidden simply does not show scroll bars.  You should definitively read the link I provided on the word `really`.  I'm not saying overflow: hidden fixes everything every time.  Yes, it has limits.  In this case, it's just simpler and have less useless markup.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is...

Just add `display:inline-block` to your div

http://jsfiddle.net/5DNFs/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can add div as child of due-total, here is the example:

```
.invoice-totals .due-total > div {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 5px;   
}​
```

Alternative:

```
.invoice-totals .due-total {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 5px;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DNFs/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/5DNFs/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow to each of the floated containers:

```
overflow: auto
```

This solves the collapsing issue. It looks to me like your styling is wrong too with the floats. Clearing floats will help too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force a [new formatting context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work/6199172#6199172) or [use a non-floating element to clear the floats (AKA. clearfix)](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2002Aug/0134.html) .

But it looks like you should be using a table for this data anyway.