# How can I tell whether an element establishes a new block formatting context using Javascript or a tool?

Tags: javascript, css, web

Some elements establish a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), depending on whether they meet certain conditions. Understanding this is quite important to be able to use floats correctly in CSS, among other things.

<s>I would like a tool to see whether a given element does establish a new block formatting context. An additional line of text in the inspector tool of Firefox like this would be ideal:</s> Apparently, a tool like this does not exist.

[image: Mock-up]

<s>If</s> since something like this doesn't already exist in a browser, I would like to develop an extension that does this myself, and to do that, I will need to be able look at each element using Javascript. Is there a DOM API call that will tell me whether a certain element establishes a new block formatting context? Something like this would be ideal:

```
var res = doesElementEstablishNewBlockFormattingContext(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

If not, I could check with Javascript whether all the conditions are met, but that would be a last resort.

**TLDR:** Is there <s>already a *tool* or *extension* or</s> an *API call* that will tell me if an an element establishes a new block formatting context?

Comment: I think you can make a JS snippet and use it as a bookmarklet, this way: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154

Comment: @GiacomoPaita: I know, but I'm missing the crucial bit of Javascript that can tell me whether an element forms a new block formatting context.

Comment: Start making the demo

Comment: Given that [the page you link to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) has the steps listed to determine whether or not a new context is established, but _doesn't_ have a handy link to an existing function, I would be willing to bet such a standard API doesn't exist.  Shouldn't be hard to write a function based on those steps though.

Comment: Your TL;DR section makes this look like a tool recommendation question.

Comment: @apaul34208: I see what you mean, but the question is asking whether such a thing exists rather then asking for a recommendation among many tools, so I thought it would be OK. Ideally, it would be in a browser's shipped dev tools.

Comment: OK, fine, I've edited the question to edit out the request for whether a tool like this exists, and I'll set a bounty again. I still think that I was in the spirit of the on-topic rules, this question was not going to attract spam or a load of opinionated recommendations.

Comment: Wow, it turns out Stack Exchange does not notify you when your question gets closed! Here's the meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/162948

Comment: I like this question, why was it closed?

Answer (score 2):

Something *like* this, but not exactly this, exists in Internet Explorer. As a proprietary part of the IE rendering engine the `hasLayout` property is used. It corresponds, *roughly*, to the creation of a new block formatting context.

`console.log(document.getElementById("id").currentStyle.hasLayout)` will show you what IE thinks. Read [this blog post](http://dev.l-c-n.com/IEW/simulations.php) for more information.

Aside from that, there are some interesting suggestions in previous questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826992/jquery-check-if-element-is-in-normal-flow), discussing what I think is roughly the same problem.

Comment: If the question hadn't been closed this answer was the closest to getting the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the rules provided by [the link in your question](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), you could write your own function for this:

```
function doesElementEstablishNewBlockFormattingContext(element) {
    var elementStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

    return elementStyle.getPropertyValue('float') != 'none' ||
        ['absolute', 'fixed'].indexOf(elementStyle.getPropertyValue('position')) !== -1 ||
        ['inline-block', 'table-cell', 'table-caption', 'flex', 'inline-flex'].indexOf(elementStyle.getPropertyValue('display')) !== -1 ||
        elementStyle.getPropertyValue('overflow') != 'visible';
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4ccbsgs5/