# Why in this scenario, a child element is crossing the borders of its parent "block formatting context"?

Tags: css

In the answer to [*How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work) the author mentions that:

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch)
>
> #### What the above line means:
>
> Because a box can only be rectangular and not irregular shaped this
>   means a new block formatting context between two floats (or even
>   beside one) will not wrap around neighbouring side floats. **The inner,
>   child boxes can only extend as far as to touch their parents left (or
>   right in RTL) edge**.

I wanted to verify this, so I created [this JS Bin test case](http://jsbin.com/ufekuc/1):

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="negative-margin">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  padding: 50px;  
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;  
}

.negative-margin {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #666;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

However as it can be seen, the contained element is crossing the left edge of its container:

[image: Test Case]

Can someone please explain what am I missing here?

## Update 1

Some people have mentioned that this is happening because of the negative margin. By following the answer to the aforementioned question, I was expecting the negative-margin not to move the contained element outside its container. To reference:

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, **block containers (such as
>   inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block
>   boxes**, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except
>   when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new
>   block formatting contexts for their contents.

And the `.table-cell` element satisfies this definition. So why is the `.negative-margin` crossing its parent's border?

Comment: because of negative margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your margin-left is causing the inner div to cross the borders...

```
margin-left: -20px;
```

Comment: Of course :) But as the negative-margin element is inside a "box formatting context", by definition, it was supposed not to cross its containing block's left edge.

Comment: The negative margin will still position the inner `div` where you tell it to... if you want it to cut off then you need to use `overflow:hidden;` on your table-cell class.

Comment: "9.1.2 Containing blocks
... **Each box is given a position with respect to its containing block, but it is not confined by this containing block**; it may overflow."

[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)

Comment: see my extra comment above (link at the end), sorry it took me a while to get the edit right...

Comment: I assume then the explanation/interpretation on that stackoverflow link is incorrect. I am referring to this part: **The inner, child boxes can only extend as far as to touch their parents left (or right in RTL) edge.**

Comment: must be, the link gave comes from w3.org... they know best, and it states there that the child is not confined by the containing block. If you increased the width of the child, then yes, it would only touch the sides of the containing block, but as you've given it a negative margin, you've altered it's **position**.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. If you update your answer to contain our comment thread, I will mark it as accepted. Otherwise I already knew that a negative `margin-left` will replace the element and move it toward the left, but I was confused, because that was contradicting with the answer to that other stackoverflow question, which surprisingly was marked as accepted.