# prevent bootstrap table being wider than span

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is a content which is usually generated dynamically. In the main part of the page there is a `<div class="span6">` . Sometimes the Table in this div becomes wider than the div itself (I ve checked the css, the width is set to 100%) . If I only put short text into the table, or if i make the div wider everything is fine.
The Questions are:

1. Why can a table become wider than `div class=spanX`? I always thought, a block element takes the width of its parent?
2. The number of characters/spaces in the respective `td` of the table can vary. How do I prevent the table from growing wider than the div? Of course I can dynamically check for the number of characters in a `ts` but what do i do with this information?

http://jsfiddle.net/vNnc6/

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MySite</title>
<meta name="author" content="me"/>

<link href="static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/profhase.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a class="brand" href="profhase">MyBrand</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>

      <div class="nav pull-right collapse nav-collapse" style="hight: 0px">
        <ul class="nav collapse nav-collapse">
          <li><p class="navbar-text">Apps: </p></li>
          <li><a href="firstapp/">AppOne <i class="icon-lock"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span2">
    <p>
      My Wonderful sidebar
    </p>
      </div>
      <div class="span6" style="background:red;">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Header1</th>
          <th>Header2</th>
          <th>Header3</th>
          <th>Header4</th>
          <th>Header5</th>
          <th>Header6</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>My first Test</td>
          <td>My second Test</td>
          <td>My third Test</td>
          <td>My fifth Test</td>
          <td>My lalalalalong long lelong long long Test</td>

          <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown Choices <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a id=1>First wonderful choice</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Thanks to the answer by FelipeAls this code did it:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Another possibility is not to use word wrap but having something like 
    ...

http://jsfiddle.net/zzmfA/

Answer (score 6):

1. I noticed the parent of `span6` is displayed as `table` but `span6` is floating. Removing the float and setting the `span*` to `display: table-cell` works: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNnc6/1/)**
   Note: there may have a more suitable class than `span*` in TB, a class which already has `display: table-cell`.
2. Other solution, but probably not what you want to achieve: the technique of *"an element with `overflow: hidden;` alongside a floating element"*: **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNnc6/2/)**
   The explanation of this magic is named [block formatting context (T. J. Koblentz' blog)](http://www.tjkdesign.com/articles/block-formatting-contexts_and_hasLayout.asp) - [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work)