# weird float clear issue

Tags: css, css-float

I have a pretty basic layout of a floated div for a left menu container column and a full width non floated div with left margin for the content area.

When i place floated div's into the content area they float and place as expected until i clear the float.

The next line of floats then appears not directly below the previous line, but all the way down below the bottom of the menu column

As you can see below there is nothing special about the layout, but the float issue is driving me nuts :)

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;">
    floated left div
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 210px; border: 1px solid blue;">
    non floated right div containing floated divs inside<br />
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">1st float</div>
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">2nd float</div>
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">3rd float</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">1st float</div>
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">2nd float</div>
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">3rd float</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">1st float</div>
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">2nd float</div>
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid green;">3rd float</div>
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

I have made a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue; http://jsfiddle.net/jP6e9/

Comment: If the container does not introduce a new block formatting context, the `clear` does not allow the larger box to be floated left. http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/jP6e9/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [clear](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-clear) property pushes elements past a `float` in the given direction.  Because of the `clear: left`, those elements are being pushed down past the large floated box.  The 'clear' property does not consider floats inside the element itself or in other [block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting).

You can easily create a new block formatting context by setting `overflow: hidden` on the wider box: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/jP6e9/7/

Comment: thank you so much, i always thought the overflow: auto would add scrollbars, but i guess thats only the case if the height is set and the content is too long :)

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those quirky situations where you need to use `overflow:auto` to get what you want.

```
<div style="margin-left: 210px; border: 1px solid blue;overflow:auto;">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jP6e9/5/)**

You need to trigger [block formatting context](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jP6e9/5/) by using the overflow property in conjunction with the float property.

See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting, http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/, and [How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work) for some good info on block formatting context.

Comment: thank you so much, i always thought the overflow: auto would add scrollbars, but i guess thats only the case if the height is set and the content is too long :)

Comment: sorry that i couldnt give the answer to both of you

Answer (score 1):

It's because you created a float with the *sidebar* `div`, but didn't float the *main* `div`. Just include the main `div` in your float, remove that massive `margin-left` and replace it with something a bit more conservative:

```
<div style="margin-left: 20px; border: 1px solid blue; float: left">
```

Finally, clear *that* float:

```
<div style="clear: left"></div>
```

Updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/jP6e9/1/

Comment: sorry i should have said that the content div needs to be the full width of rest of the remaining screen space, else i would have normally laid it out as per your update

Answer (score 0):

you can use the display: table-cell for right div,like this:

```
<div class="left">floated left div</div>
<div class="right">
  non floated right div containing floated divs inside <br />
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <div class="floatItem"> float</div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

the css code:

```
.left {
  float: left; 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.right {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-cell;
}
.floatItem {
  float: left; 
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

please view the [deom](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/FDBfm).

Answer (score 0):

Float none stops an element to stop wraping around adjacent floating clild. By default all, elements have float none. Clear both stop element to wrap around any floating child from left or right. For more details and live examples, visit my tutorial,
                 http://tutorial.techaltum.com/css_float.html.