# equivalent tr of CSS?

Tags: css

How do you separate the menu bar from the body in a div, to place everything after contact below it, is there a corresponding code like a newline?  I would really appreciate the help :) Thanks in advance
here's a link of picture shot:

**CSS**

```css
/* because of the * default code it takes out all margin and padding */
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#container {
    display: table;
}
#row {
    display: table-row;
}
#left, #right, #middle {
    display: table-cell;
}
#row {
    display: table-row;
}
#left, #right, #middle {
    display: table-cell;
}
body {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: ABC;
    padding: 50px;
    margin: auto;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
li + li {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    color: #222;  /*changes the color of all item font color in menu bar */
    background: #eee; /*changes the background color of Menu bar */
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #666; /* changes hover bg color of any menu item being pointed*/
}
a:active {
    color: #f2f75e;
    background: #0090cf;
}
/* Child Menu Styles */
.level-two {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -9999px;
    width: 100px;
}
li:hover .level-two {
    left: 0;
}
.level-two li {
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<h1>
  <ul class="level-one">
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Drops</a>
      <ul class="level-two">
        <li> <a href="#">One</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Two</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Three</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="row">
      <div id="left">
        <h4>Left Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="middle">
        <h4>Middle Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        <h4>Right Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

Comment: Can you add some more context about what you are trying to accomplish? It sounds like you need to start using floats rather than table-style display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `clearfix` class on both of .

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EWtN4/)**

```
.clearfix{
clear:both;
}
```

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/bKaxg/220/)**

Comment: clear: both means newline? another question how do you extend the menu bar to fit the width? to be able to get a layout like this? link file shot picture: http://postimg.org/image/f7rze5wuv/

Comment: OMG you are superb, this is a lot better, but i can't understand it, i'm going to try to understand. I'll vote for your answer :) Kudos

Comment: How do you stretch the menu bar to align with the body? http://s23.postimg.org/4isztvn2z/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.png

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to the `clear` property is to trigger a new *block formatting context* on the menu in order to contain the floats inside `.level-one` :

```
.level-one {
    /* trigger block formatting context to contain floats. */
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/mrYdV/1/

[Here is a list of other property/value pairs that trigger block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

[W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)

[Bulletproof backwards-compatible version](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/)

There is a great answer with more details covering this method at [How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work#answer-6199172)

Answer (score 1):

The [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property will do this for you. You can add it to your `#container` for example:

```
#container {
    display: table;
    clear:both;
}
```

**Clear** means something like:

> clear all elements on both sides of this element

Comment: clear: both means newline? another question how do you extend the menu bar to fit the width? to be able to get a layout like this? link file shot picture: http://s23.postimg.org/mazuts2aj/zzzzzzzz.png

Comment: You could try working around with *width: 100%;* but I really think you should post this question as a new one.