# Background color not showing in wrapper

Tags: html, css

for some reason the #CCC background (100% width) doesn't show up with my code below. Would you know why? Tks

http://jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/5/

```
.wrap100pc {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ccc;
}

#bottom-left {
    float: left;
    width: 490px;;
    background: #5421c2;
    height: 300px;
}

#bottom-right {
    float: right;
    width: 490px;;
    background: #2ec4a6;
    height: 300px;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;

}


<div class="wrap100pc clear">
<div id="bottom-left">bottom-left</div>
<div id="bottom-right">bottom-right</div>
</div>  <!-- End DIV Wrap100pc Clear-->
```

Comment: the problem is in your `.clear` style definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the background back, add `overflow:auto` to your `#wrapper` div.

```
.wrap100pc {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DzaCq/1/)**

The floated child divs have their own block formatting context and applying overflow:auto (or hidden) produces the result you seek. For an in-depth answer about block formatting context, see [How does the CSS Block Formatting Context work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work)

Comment: overflow:hidden; is fine too :)

Comment: Bah, beat me to it! :) Perhaps explain more about why (i.e. the floats)

Comment: @KevinCittadini - was in the process of writing that and updating when you posted your comment ;)

Comment: @kunalbhat - I was adding the explanation when you posted your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer j08691 but for some reason it did not work with my full code - would you know why? Here is an updated fiddle zith the full code: jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/5

Comment: You have some typos in the code in that fiddle, but more importantly which div in that latest example is exhibiting the problem and needs to be stretched?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I fixed the typos and it partially fixed my issues. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/6/ Remaining one: if I want bottom-left and bottom-right to be aligned horizontally to the center of the page, do I need to create an additional wrapper of ie. 980px within wrap 100pc? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I just checked your latest fiddle and it looks like your bottom left and right divs are horizontally aligned/centered. What am I missing?

Comment: Currently bottom left is aligned to the left side of the screen and bottom right to the right side. What I'd like is both of them (next to each other) in the middle of the page (like the first 2 intro DIVs). Possible without an additional wrapping? Tks

Comment: No you'll need a wrapper to center them together on the same line. If it was just one element you could use the margin:0 auto trick but that won't work if they're together.

Comment: Oki doki. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to add `overflow:auto` to `div#wrapper`. Your `.clear` style definition does not fix `.wrapper` height.

Changing it to:

```
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

solves your problem.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for some reason it did not work with my full code -  would you know why? Here is an updated fiddle zith the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/5/

Comment: @Greg yes. you need to add a full wrapper to your centered `div.wrap980px` and apply a `background-color`. Here is your full code updated: [http://jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/7/). **There is no need to apply `overflow:auto`**

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `float:left` to the wrapper too:

http://jsfiddle.net/DzaCq/3/

```
.wrap100pc {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ccc;
    float:left;
}
```

EDIT: If you don't want it floated, the other answer using `overflow` would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a `height` for the `.wrap100pc`.

Hope that helps!