# How can I make my DIV that wraps buttons use some vertical space?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML where the float-left and float-right classes do just that:

```
<div class="block-footer">
   <button class="medium float-left">A</button>
   <button class="medium float-left">A</button>
   <button class="medium float-left">A</button>
   <button class="medium float-right">A</button>
   <button class="medium float-right">A</button>
</div>
```

This works but my div seems to occupy no vertical space and that's a problem for what follows. When I do this:

```
<div class="block-footer">
   <button class="medium float-left">A</button>
   <button class="medium float-left">A</button>
   <button class="medium float-left">A</button>
   <button class="medium float-right">A</button>
   <button class="medium">A</button>
</div>
```

Then the DIV occupies space.

So how can I get some buttons to float to the left and some to the right and still have the DIV use some vertical space?

Comment: Take a look at http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ you can try using this via your own `clearfix` class for the floated buttons. Like this: `.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { display: table; content: " "; } .clearfix:after { clear: both; }` I however have not seen how this works on `button` elements but give it a try.. it also depends on the browsers you need to support, alternative you can add a clearfix `div` as the last child in `block-footer`. Also so you are aware, if you float the `block-footer` that also makes it wrap around its floated children.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `overflow:auto` on your container div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bRSz2/)**

This is due to [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting). Check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work) about how it works. Essentially the floats do just that, float, and act like they are removed from the document flow, which causes the container div to collapse.

Comment: This works but can you tell me. Is this different / better than clearing floats ?

Comment: Well with this method you don't need to add any other elements to clear the floats, nor do you need the old clearfix hack workaround.