# CSS Float - The content stays in the default stack position

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two divs in the page with same width and height.

if I give float: left to the first div, the second div goes up (which is fine because the floated element is taken out of the normal document flow)

But, why the content of the div still shows in the default stack position?

JsFiddle is given below

http://jsfiddle.net/xR9Rd/2/

```
<div class="box0">Box 0</div>   
<div class="box1">Box1</div>

.box0 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
}
.box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The `float:left` is actually normal behaviour of a div. Therefore nothing should happen. I like the explanation in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23603302/2582496) answer from @BoltClock also.

Comment: @jPO: That's plainly wrong. The `float` property defaults to `none` on _any_ element. No elements are taken from the normal flow by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The width of each box is 100 pixels. When you float one over the other, there is no more horizontal space left in the second box for its content because it's completely occupied by the float, so the content has to wrap to the next line (and overflow the 100-pixel *height* in that process).

If you make the second box wider, [the content will appear next to the float](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xR9Rd/3):

```
.box1 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The content will never appear *behind* the float, however, because inline content will always wrap around floats (otherwise, floating won't be very useful).

Comment: @abhitalks: `overflow: hidden` causes the box to generate a block-formatting context, which makes it *immune* to surrounding floats. That causes the entire box to shift outside of the float and sit right next to it instead.

Comment: @abhitalks: It's a strange side-effect - normally you would expect the content to just disappear while the background remains behind the other box - but it is how it is.

Comment: Ya, I thought so. That's why I sought your attention. In fact applying just any `overflow` will cause this. The `div` already has a `block` context so that shouldn't actually matter!

Comment: @abhitalks: Well, a block formatting context isn't quite the same as a block-level element; a `div` by itself doesn't generate a formatting context automatically. It's a rather complicated topic that's outside the scope of this question, but there are articles you can read if you want to find out more: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/blockformatting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, especially the second one. Great learning. That clears my confusion but will take some time to sink in.

Comment: @BoltClock: I have got few more doubts when I started playing on this html further. Can you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624372/how-the-block-element-works-inside-a-floated-div

Comment: A question was marked as a duplicate of this (http://stackoverflow.com/q/23638434/1026459). However, your answer doesn't seem to fit in the situation of this: http://jsfiddle.net/6p52h/ vs this: http://jsfiddle.net/6p52h/2/ . Can you clarify why the element is placed on a new line when width is defined, but overlaps when no width is defined?

Answer (score 4):

When you float an element to left, it is taken out of the flow, the next element is laid out as if the first one did not exist. Then the floated element is placed. the textual content is given a special treatment such that the text starts flowing around the floated element.

In the above example, the first div was taken out of flow and the second div was placed ( still has the block context and starts from extreme left ) as if no other element existed. Then the floated div is placed. Since both has same size, there is an overlap. Then the text float mechanism kicks in and try to place the text around the floated div.  The text container ( box1 ) does not have any space after the floated div ( both are overlapping ) it is naturally pushed down. 
one way to see it aligned to the box is to increase the second box width, so that the text gets contained.

Other option is to add margin-left to the second div so that the second div starts at an offset from the floated div and there is space for the content to align it self around the first div. See the example fiddle

```
.box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sreekarun/xR9Rd/8/

Comment: I have got few more doubts when I started playing on this html further. Can you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624372/how-the-block-element-works-inside-a-floated-div

Answer (score 2):

In the above case both boxes will have their top-left corner aligned with each other. In this case, the browser cannot display the text in second div at the very top because the box is 100px wide and has 100px wide floated box *before* it. The text renders at first available spot in the div (which is where the floated content ends).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box
{
width:200px;
}
.box0 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
}
.box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float:right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
<div class="box0">Box 0</div>   
<div class="box1">Box1</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please explain what is the problem with the initial html in the question?

Comment: first partitioning the div.main div in that two divs left and right this is right format to write the code

Answer (score 0):

It's because `DIV's` are by default, `Blocks` elements.. so even if you give a `float` propertie to first div, the second one still have the default `display` attribute.

So, add `display: inline-block` to the second block and there you go.

jsFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/xR9Rd/4/

```
.box1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the default `display: block` behaves the way it does.

Comment: I agree, even if this solves it, it's not the answer OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use float anymore , just display the two divs as inline-block and reduce a little bit the width of each div

```
<div class="box0">Box 0</div>   
<div class="box1">Box1</div>

.box0 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: brown;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 }
 .box1 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 }
```

Comment: Please do not delete and repost answers verbatim just because they were downvoted. This is considered an abuse of the system, not to mention it could get downvoted again.

Comment: my answer is downvoted because i voted up for it , so i am sorry

Comment: What are you talking about? You can't vote on your own answers. If your answer was downvoted that means somebody else downvoted your answer.

Comment: because when somebody vote up his answer , stack overflow downvoted it and i am sorry again because i voted up my previous answer

Comment: But **you can't vote on your own answers**. The system will not downvote your answer just because you tried upvoting it, all it does is give you an error. Like I said, somebody else chose to downvote your answer. It was not the system.

Comment: Anyway , i am so sorry