# Interaction between floated and "non floated" elements

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="inner1">
     LINE1  
  </div>
  <div id="inner2">
    LINE2 
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
.wrapper{
    width:400px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #0FC;
}
#inner1{
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background-color: #69C;
}
#inner2{
    float:none;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    background-color: #C09;
}
```

Output:

[image]

If we change `width:auto` to e.g. `width:20%` (on `#inner2`) we get the following output:

[image]

Why does `#inner2` collapse under `#inner1`? There is enough space next to `#inner1`!

What makes this difference between `width:auto` and `width:xx%`?

---

Also, I'd like an explanation for the lack of right margin of `#inner1` and left margin of `#inner2` in the first example. This is  margin-collapse effect, isn't it? Why does it happen here?

Comment: Here is a CSSDesk of this question: http://cssdesk.com/gpuyP

Comment: What browser are you seeing the lines wrap? In Firefox 29.0.1 and Chrome 34 it seems to work the way you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The float:none is affecting your dimensions.

[Difference between auto and %](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/)

[Using clear:both instead of float:none](http://jsfiddle.net/N3V52/)

change inner 2 from:

```
float:none;
```

to

```
  float:left;
```