# Why the content overlaps?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have looked through the chrome developer tools but do not understand why this happens.
I expected to see the blocks one below the other. But I need the child has absolute positioning block to be animatable.

### CURRENT RESULTS

[image]

### CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
}

.sibling {
    position: static;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">
        <p class="red">Lorem ipsum ...</p>        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sibling">
    <p class="blue">Lorem ipsum ...</p>       
</div>
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rnrlabs/rcc18vkL/)

Comment: What are you expecting to have happen?  It's hard to suggest a fix without knowing what you're trying to do.  Also note that sibling has been placed outside of the container in your code above....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, Because when you use `position: absolute;` that takes your `div.child` element out of the document's regular flow and you've set `position: relative;` to your `div.container` but your `div.container` doesn't have any height (0px), that's why `div.sibling` overlaps the `div.container`.

If you set `margin: 0px;` to `p` tag then `div.sibling` completely overlaps the `div.container` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/78rcu0dk/)**

**Solution:** First of All, There's no way to do it as you want using CSS. You must remove `position: absolute;` or set height to your `div.container`.

**[EDITED]**

`div.container` height is 0px on chrome developer tools.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is another 'BFC'（Block Formatting Context） question. when you add position:absolute or fixed to your element, the element create a BFC . the BFC don't share margin with other element.

You may search something about BFC or read [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work/6199172#6199172)

My solution is add `overflow:hidden` to `.sibling` to make `.sibling` into another BFC

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcc18vkL/1/)