# Relative position of picture as background in flex box

Tags: css, background, position, flexbox, absolute

I'd like to make an image with opacity as a background in a container without inheritance to the children boxes.

My code:

```css
body{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.container{
 border-color: white;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
    display: flex;
 width: 300px;
 min-height: 300px;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;  
}
.box{
 opacity: 0.2;
 border-color: white;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 flex: 1;
}
.box1{background-color: yellow;}
.box2{background-color: green;}
.box3{background-color: blue;}
.box4{background-color: red;}
.box5{background-color: orange;}

.container img{
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
 <img src="http://www.tapeciarnia.pl/tapety/normalne/191848_swiecace_kule_grafika_3d.jpg" alt=""> 
 <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
 <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
 <div class="box box3">Box 3</div>
 <div class="box box4">Box 4</div>
 <div class="box box5">Box 5</div>
</div>
 
</body>
```

I'd like to put these colorful boxes on that image, but when i'm trying to use `position: relative;` with `z-index: -1;` to image and `position: absolute;` to boxes then flex positioning doesn't work.

Could you explain why flex box don't work with absolutely positioning and give the solution of that problem?

Comment: I'm using opacity to boxes just to see background image when they will move corectly, so it's temporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine when you set `position: relative` to `.container` and `position: absolute` to `.container img`.

```css
body{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.container{
 border-color: white;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
    display: flex;
 width: 300px;
 min-height: 300px;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column; 
  position: relative;
}
.box{
 opacity: 0.2;
 border-color: white;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 flex: 1;
}
.box1{background-color: yellow;}
.box2{background-color: green;}
.box3{background-color: blue;}
.box4{background-color: red;}
.box5{background-color: orange;}

.container img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
 <img src="http://www.tapeciarnia.pl/tapety/normalne/191848_swiecace_kule_grafika_3d.jpg" alt=""> 
 <div class="box box1">Box 1</div>
 <div class="box box2">Box 2</div>
 <div class="box box3">Box 3</div>
 <div class="box box4">Box 4</div>
 <div class="box box5">Box 5</div>
</div>
 
</body>
```

I think flexbox doesn't work right with absolutely positioned elements because those elements create new block formatting context: [BFC link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work)

Comment: Thank you so much! The only problem is that image not fits to the container but  I already did it by trial-and-error method :)
It works well when I put `position: absolute` to container, `position: relative;` to boxes and `position: absolute;` to image.

Your answer about reason of problem abosolutly positioning in flex box really helped ;D

Answer (score 0):

I repaired my code by putting `position: absolute;` to container and by changing `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` on image and `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` on boxes.

Well, It seems that I still don't understand position property enough. So I'd be grateful, if someone could answer, why it didn't work previously.